# How to send value with route - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router-dom

this is my route:

```
<Route path="/about-cards/:id?" component={AboutCards} />
```

then this is my url:

```
http://localhost:3000/about-cards?id=1
```

inside my `AboutCards` component:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('this.props.match.params.id',this.props.match.params.id)
```

but it print a `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.props.match.params` will gives only url params and not query params.

Use `this.props.location.search`.It will gives you `?id=1`.
Do some processing to get `id`.

In modern browsers that support [`URL API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL),it can be achived using [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

```
let queryParams = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);

queryParams.get('id'); //instead id,one can query param name.
// will give 1
```